# Groups of commands in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I have this shell script call cpdir:

```
(cd $1 ; tar -cf - . ) | (cd $2 ; tar -xvf - )
```

When I ran it, the main shell should create two processes (subshells) to execute both groups of commands concurrently. However, how can the shell make sure that both processes change to appropriate directories, then first process package the content of the directory and send to the second process for unpacking?

Why is there no race condition? Is it a rule that every command of every process will execute in order, although processes can be parallel?

i.e. first process will run "cd $1", and then second process will run "cd $2" (or it should be execute the same time as the first process? Not sure), then first process will package everything and finally send to second process.

Although, one little thing I don't know about tar:

```
tar -cf - .
```

I know the dot (.) is the content of current directory. However, what's the '-' in the command?

Comment: the '-' means: use stdin/stdout instead of file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `cd` because tar has a `-C` option which tells it to change to a directory. So you can simply use a command such as:

```
tar -C $1 -cvf - . | tar -C $2 -xvf -
```

`-` means stdin/stdout. The first hyphen tells `tar` to write to stdout. The second one tells `tar` to read from stdin.

Since `-` is the default, you don't even need to specify it. You can shorten your command to:

```
tar -C $1 -c . | tar -C $2 -x
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still the questions remains: is it true that, two groups of commands (commands in the parentheses is a group of command, each command is separate by the semicolon ';', and be executed sequentially). I thought when two processes run concurrently, it has no order. It means, the second process could just even cd to folder $2 and execute the tar command even before the first process changes directory. Is it a rule that Linux enforces groups of commands wait for each other?

Comment: The two groups are launched at the same time so the `cd` commands could take place in any order. However, both groups are connected with a pipe. The second tar command is waiting for stdin, which is coming from the first tar command. One is a producer and the other is a consumer. They're not "sequential". The first tar is streaming data to the second, so they are running in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

As those groups run in independent processes, it doesn't matter which `cd` command runs first: each process has its own working directory.

So changing working directory does not affect the respectively other process.

Answer (score 0):

You are piping the commands in your case. The result you expect is not very clear to me.
By the way, my GNU tar has no "-" value for this "-f" option.
So you commands might be not portable.

Comment: Not sure about that. But I tried on two different Linux and it works.